# bash script to update a xml field with in a specific record

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I'm a new bee to shell scripting.

I an xml record :

```
 <record name="lteRanRf">
    <key name="fapService" value="1"/>
    <field name="referenceSignalPower" value="-10"/>
    <field name="phyCellId" value="2175"/>
 </record>
 <record name="neighborcell">
    <key name="fapService" value="1"/>
    <field name="referenceSignalPower" value="-10"/>
    <field name="phyCellId" value="2175"/>
 </record>
```

I need to replace the value of phyCellId only in the lteRanRf record. 
   Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to replace it with what?

Comment: I need to update the value of phyCellId from 2175 to a user input value, only in record lteRanRf and i'm allowed to use only bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Below awk command will change the value of `phyCellId` field in the Record `lteRanRf`.

```
$ awk -F'"' -v RS="</record>" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS; ORS=RS;} /lteRanRf/ {$14=1111;}1' file
 <record name="lteRanRf">
    <key name="fapService" value="1"/>
    <field name="referenceSignalPower" value="-10"/>
    <field name="phyCellId" value="1111"/>
 </record>
 <record name="neighborcell">
    <key name="fapService" value="1"/>
    <field name="referenceSignalPower" value="-10"/>
    <field name="phyCellId" value="2175"/>
 </record>
```

Value you want to change is given inside the awk command (ie, `$14=1111;`)

Comment: can you please explain how this command works? If i run this command the entire xml is getting printed. Its not changing phyCellId :(

Comment: Then it may contain spaces

Comment: I copied exactly what you have posted and worked from that. Its so hard to parse XML with regex.